# Density of product of uniform random variable and exponential random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, solution-verification

I was trying to find density $\rho_{\xi\eta}$ if $\xi \sim U(0,1)$ and $\eta \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and they are independent.

Using convolution of product, I got

$\rho_{\xi\eta}(v) = \mathbb{1}_{\{v\geq0\}}\int_{0}^{1}\lambda e^{-\lambda v u^{-1}}u^{-1}du$, there $\mathbb{1}$ is and indicator function.

But as I know this is the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), so It can be evaluated in elementary functions.
Did I do something wrong and I need to find mistakes in calculations or is it the right answer?

**Here is my calculations:**

As I said, $\mathbb{1}_{x \in A}(x)$ is the Indicator function and it equals $1$ if $x \in A$ and equals $0$ if $x \not\in A$.

Using this we can write down densities of $\xi$ and $\eta$:

$\rho_{\xi}(x)=\mathbb{1}_{0\leq x
\leq 1}(x)$,

$\rho_{\eta}(y) = \mathbb{1}_{y \geq 0}(y)\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$.

I assume $\mathbb{1}_{0\leq u \leq 1} := \mathbb{1}_{0\leq u \leq 1}(u), \mathbb{1}_{\frac{v}{u}\geq0} : = \mathbb{1}_{\frac{v}{u}\geq0}(v, u)$.

$\rho_{\xi\eta}(v) \stackrel{(1)}{=} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho_{\xi}(u)\rho_{\eta}(\frac{v}{u})\frac{1}{|u|}du =\\ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbb{1}_{0\leq u \leq 1} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\frac{v}{u}\geq0}\lambda e^{-\lambda v u^{-1}}|u^{-1}|du= \\ \int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{1}_{\frac{v}{u}\geq0}\lambda e^{-\lambda v u^{-1}}u^{-1}du = \mathbb{1}_{\{v\geq0\}}\int_{0}^{1}\lambda e^{-\lambda v u^{-1}}u^{-1}du$.

Equality (1) is just using formula of convolution of product.

If I used some uncommon notations or I can make my solution clearer, please let me know.

Comment: The fact that this can (does it?) be evaluated by elementary functions is no indication that you did something wrong. Can you show the steps that led to your formula?

Comment: @KurtG., I added calculations.

Comment: Convolution of PDF's of independent  random variables gives PDF of  **sum** of the random variables.

Comment: @kludg OP means convolution of *product* but I will add an answer how I would do that.

Comment: @kludg, I made some corrections to make my solution clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Not sure why you integrate from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and there might be other problems.

This is how I would do it:
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P\big\{\xi\,\eta\le x\big\}=\textstyle\int_0^1\int_0^{x/u}\lambda\, e^{-\lambda y}  \,dy\,du=\int_0^1 1-e^{-\lambda x/u }\,du\\[2mm]
&=\textstyle 1-e^{-\lambda x}+\lambda x\,\Gamma(0,\lambda x)
\end{align}
(according to Wolfram Alpha) where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):
$$
\Gamma(s,x)=\textstyle\int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}\,dt\,.
$$
Now differentiate that w.r.t. $x$ to get the PDF of $\xi\,\eta\,:$
$$
p_{\xi\eta}(x)=\textstyle\int_0^1 \frac{\lambda}{u} e^{-\lambda x/u}\,du=\lambda\,\Gamma(0,\lambda x)\,.
$$

Comment: I just use this formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables. I did derivation of this formula and I know that this just is corollary of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables. So I used as limits $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ but anyway I changed them according to indicators.

Comment: @perepelart We should use only formulas only that we understand. Nothing runs between $-\infty$ and zero in your case and my answer is fully self-contained. Please get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not trying to solve the problem by any means, I am mostly trying to understand that is wrong with my solution. Now I can not see problem in using such limits and changing them according to indicators. Of course I can be wrong and will try to understand do I.

Comment: @perepelart My last line shows that you did nothing wrong. Why did you think that?

Comment: Thanks! I did not see your last line and did double checking -- differentiated your answer and it coinced with my answer as well (after I did substition in my integral I got incompleted gamma-function as well)! Now I see that you have already did it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Let $Z=\xi \eta$ with $\xi\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $\eta\sim\operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$. Then we have for the conditioned random variable
$$
Z|\eta\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,\eta)
$$
The joint distribution for $(Z,\eta)$ is $f_{Z,\eta}(z,\eta)=f_{Z|\eta}(z|\eta)f_\eta(\eta)$. Integrating the joint density w.r.t. $\eta$ should then give the distribution for $Z$.  We write
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_Z(z)
&=\int_0^\infty f_{Z|\eta}(z|\eta)f_\eta(\eta)\,\mathrm d\eta\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\eta}\mathbf 1_{z\in(0,\eta)} \lambda e^{-\lambda\eta}\,\mathrm d\eta\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\eta}\mathbf 1_{\eta\in(z,\infty)} \lambda e^{-\lambda\eta}\,\mathrm d\eta\\
&=\int_z^\infty \frac{1}{\eta} \lambda e^{-\lambda\eta}\,\mathrm d\eta\\
&=\lambda\int_{\lambda z}^\infty u^{0-1} e^{-u}\,\mathrm du\\
&=\lambda\Gamma(0,\lambda z),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Gamma(a,z)=\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt$ is the (upper) incomplete gamma function. The is the same result obtained by @Kurt G and is the final solution to the product distribution. Note that this result does not simplify to elementary functions but you can express it in terms of
$$
f_Z(z)=-\lambda\operatorname{Ei}(-\lambda z),
$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^\infty e^{-t}/t\,\mathrm dt$ is the exponential integral.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew that conditioning on something is strong method to prove lots of things in discrete case, but I becoming more and more convincing that in continuos case it is the strong technique as well.

Comment: @perepelart you can do a lot with conditioning for sure.